# Why I always get the error env: ipython: No such file or directory when I run the Pyspark with IPython

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I want to run the Pyspark terminal with IPython. 
I have run the command in the right directory such as

`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython ./bin/pyspark` or `IPYTHON=1 IPYTHON_OPTS="--pylab" ./bin/pyspark`

but what I finally get is `env: ipython: No such file or directory`

I have installed the Anaconda using `brew cask install` and I am sure I have the pyspark file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command works for me. It seems that your environment for ipython is not properly set. Try to see if this works in your shell

```
which ipython
```

You should get a path of your ipython. If not then try to reinstall anaconda and set the path properly in your bash profile.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have ipython in your OS install it by this commande `sudo pip install ipython` this commande help you to install ipython and add it to your python libraries

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please expand your answer.

Comment: `sudo pip install ipython` to install ipython and add it to your python libraries

Comment: Could you please include that info on the answer itself, so it would be complete? Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information on best practices for answering on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I had the some issue and i had fixed it by Uninstalling anaconda and installing it again from conda.io. Now it works fine!!!